# MSSQL give new primary key in table 1 and update corresponding keys in table 2

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a product and product_detail table pair that I need to copy the data from and update the primary key.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is copy last night's data from both tables, give them new primary keys so they don't clash with the current data and insert back into the table with some of the information updated - pk/fk, update_date, and two fields flagged as something different.

I can't make changes to the tables, so I can't use update cascade.  We have a file that does an End of Day batch and inserts the data into the tables.  We also have a file that is updated every time a transaction happens during the day, so what I thought I could do is copy last nights data, update the keys so they didn't clash, and update that new set of data with whatever comes in from the file during the day.  The way it is now, our users have to wait until the end of the day to see where we are.  With updating during the day, they can see the balance as the day progresses.

I believe I will have to grab the information out of the main table, get a new pk, update the other info, and pass that new pk to the second table to replace the original fk it has and do it row by row.

Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: @How would you link the new set of data with the data that comes in from the file?  Not sure I understand the process fully

Comment: Sorry, that isn't really clear.  The file hooks up to a completely different key that I do a look up as I parse thru the file.  So essentially, I copy everything from last night, and update the detail for that particular transaction with the info from the file.  That way we have last nights data plus any updates made so far during the day.